# How to "disable" default primary keys in djongo

Tags: python, django, djongo

I'm getting this error after upgrading to djongo 1.3.6

`ERRORS: some_app.Some_Class: (models.E026) The model cannot have more than one field with 'primary_key=True'.`

this is the class giving the error:

```
# some_app/some_class.py 

from djongo import models


class Some_Class(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    event_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    league = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    event_date = models.IntegerField()
    event_text = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    event_group_id = models.IntegerField()
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

as you can see I have only one PK defined, but apparently djongo is creating the another one. Any idea on how to disable this djongo behaviour????

Comment: I Just wonder why you want to reinvent the wheel if you already have the wheels.but id you just want to generate a random id for that either use uuid4 or create a function which will generate a random  id every time

Comment: good question, I'm just taking over somebody else project and my task was to upgrade python and all its packages. For more context, this was working before just fine before the upgrade. I checked djongo documentation but not luck

Comment: From djongo's docs `By default the ObjectIdField internally sets primary_key as True.` Mb you should switch `_id` and `event_id` field types and remove `primary_key=True` from *eventually* `_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Django models only support a single-column primary key. If you don't specify primary_key = True for the field in your model, Django will automatically create a column id as a primary key.